# grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1. Check your device.map

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

I was rebuilding linux kernel, and when I ran command

`sudo make modules_install install`

I got this message

`grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1. Check your device.map.`

but I ignore it and try to reboot, then I can't get into ubuntu anymore.

How can I fix it ?

I tried to use USB to boot the system, and try `sudo fdisk -l` and there's no /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 like it should have had.